# Detect missing beans when using Spring

Tags: java, spring

When using Spring to inject beans, there's a chance such dependencies are missing. For example:

```java
@Component
public class Bar {

    @Autowired
    public Bar(MyRepository rep) {
        //access db and do a lot of stuff
        List<Entity> list = rep.getAll();
        ...
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    @Autowired
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

This code should compile but when starting up the app, if there's no `Bar` bean that can be injected the application will fail to start. So I want to know about this failures before trying to start the app. Also, starting up the application will trigger the code in the constructor of the beans which perform slow operations.

The question: Is it possible to create a test or a gradle task that validates that all dependencies are fulfilled without having to start application?

Comment: Please show MyRepository class too

Comment: I think you want an annotation processor that processes the autowired and component annotations alongside springs that verifies the dependencies. There may already be one out there.

Comment: I was hoping Spring provided something like this, or at least some utility that can be easily used to resolve such dependencies